# Row of thumbnails works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox (bootstrap)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following snippet:
http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/51/

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span3">
            <button type="button" class="btn">
                <img class="img-rounded" src="http://s15.postimg.org/gn3znajvf/img1.png">
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <button type="button" class="btn">
                <img class="img-rounded" src="http://s17.postimg.org/4wx50qtin/img2.png">
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

A simple row of thumbnails. It looks good in Chrome, but somehow does not work in Firefox / IE.

Am I doing something wrong? I believe that everything in the page is supposed to be cross-browser compatible.

Comment: what do you mean its not working, in what way, also your fiddle is completely empty

Comment: jsfiddle fixed. The thumbnails are on top of each other: http://s22.postimg.org/843o1s2ap/Screenshot.jpg

Comment: Where is your css? `UL` elements display a vertical list when not styled

Comment: There is no additional CSS, just bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are big and those images are inside `.btn` class which has `display:inline-block` - this means buttons will extend to accommodate your image.

Next thing, `.span3` is responsive and this span width is being smaller/bigger depending on your screen size but not your `.btn` which has image.

**Solution:**
You can fix it by making your btn to block level. Apply class `btn-block`.

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block">
                    <img class="img-rounded" src="http://s15.postimg.org/gn3znajvf/img1.png"/>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li class="span3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block">
                    <img class="img-rounded" src="http://s17.postimg.org/4wx50qtin/img2.png"/> 
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/Y7XE7/1/